# What is a good (free) library to make a contour plot in Java?

Tags: java, plot, contour

What are good libraries to create a Contour plot in Java?
The class [ContourPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ContourPlot.html) in JFreeChart is deprecated, and a reference is made to the XYBlockRenderer class.
I would like to have some suggestions.

Comment: Edited, I hope it fits the rules now.

Comment: I've written recently some simple implementation of filled 2D contour plot in Java and JavaFX - https://github.com/bluevoxel/Contour2DPlot. Maybe you will find it usefull.

Comment: @bluevoxel sounds interesting but it's GPL.

Comment: @Jason S Why "but"?

Comment: because GPL for libraries forces the containing application to become GPL... which despite what FSF promotes, is a dead end for anyone doing any work in a commercial environment, even if the application is not for-profit (e.g. in my case I work for a semiconductor manufacturer, we produce software tools that are cost-free but not open-source, and we won't touch GPL libraries)

Comment: ...and even when we do produce open-source software, we release it under licenses that are not compatible with GPL without the containing application becoming GPL. (can't remember which one at the moment, maybe Apache) *note*: LGPL is fine.

Comment: @Sander as much as we as individuals may appreciate the relevancy of this question (and I certainly do, I found it in a google search), SO considers it inappropriate because it is a software recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing I could find is [Jzy3D](http://www.jzy3d.org/index.php).

In their [gallery](http://www.jzy3d.org/gallery.php) is a chart with the title "Filled Contour Demo (2d picture)".

[image]

Maybe this would be a starting point.