# Making a contourplot in Java from large data-arrays

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, contour, jscience

I have the following question:

Is there a Tool to make an contureplot in Java during the runtime out of large data arrays?

I found many post related to this question (also here [contourplot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352355/what-is-a-good-free-library-to-make-a-contour-plot-close-as-possible-to-this) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245424/opensource-java-library-for-surface-plots-contour-plots)) but I didn't found any solution to make a fast contourplot out of large arrays.

I have tried to do it with [Jsci](http://jsci.sourceforge.net/) and also with [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). With [Jsci](http://jsci.sourceforge.net/) I got problems displaying the  image and with [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) it takes veeeerrrrrryyyyy long to make a plot.

What I seek is somthing like matplotlib in python. And the image should look somehow like [this](http://www.davidpace.com/images/stories/physics/d17_book33_vf_pt64ms.png)

Comment: +1 for citing your research, but _veeeerrrrrryyyyy long_ is not constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for [`XYBlockRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBlockRenderer.html). The image shown in the API is from `XYBlockChartDemo1` in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). It appears to render 10,000 blocks, 100 x 100, nearly instantly. If your experience varies, editing your question to include a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might reveal the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. With XYBlockRenderer is works perfect. And I figured out that while using XYBlockRenderer i should create a 'final ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>' from the input data or somethink simular to speed thinks up (factor 1000 or higher)

Comment: @HansDampf: +1 for caching; the demo (re-)calculates each block every time, and it lags noticeably for larger sizes.

Comment: thanks for that. i have reworked the XYBlockRenderer-Example code to plot every 3D-Data-Array. Is it likely that I post it here somehow?

Comment: @HansDampf: I don't think the demos are licensed for distribution; same for derived works. The experimental demo mentioned [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19281&p=55490&hilit=XYBlockRenderer#p55490) is no longer [extant](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2522/tree/trunk/experimental/org/jfree/experimental/chart/). Of course, you can always [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) your own original work.