# JFreeChart Performance

Tags: performance, jfreechart, time-series

I'm trying to plot some graphs simultaneously:
Each representing an attribute and displays the results for several objects each containing its own data items series.
I encounter very bad performance using either add(...) or addOrUpdate(...) methods of the TimeSeries -  time for plotting ~16,000 items is about 60 seconds.
I read about the performance issue - http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=12130&start=0 - but it seems to me like it is much worse in my case for some reason.

1. I'd like to understand whether this is truly the performance that I may squeeze out of the module (2.5GHz machine running windows - I doubt that).
2. How can I get my application accelerated with this respect?

Here is a basic version of the code (note that it is all done in a dedicated thread):

```
/* attribute -> (Object -> graph values) */
protected HashMap<String,HashMap<Object,Vector<TimeSeriesDataItem>>> m_data = 
  new HashMap<String,HashMap<Object,Vector<TimeSeriesDataItem>>>();

public void loadGraph() {
    int items = 0;
    for (String attr : m_data.keySet()) 
        for (Object obj : m_data.get(attr).keySet())
            for (TimeSeriesDataItem dataItem : m_data.get(attr).get(obj))
                items++;
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // plot each graph
    for (String attr : m_data.keySet()) {  
        GraphXYPlot plot = m_plots.get(attr);
        plot.addToObservation(m_data.get(attr));
    }

    System.err.printf("Time for plotting %d items is:  %d ms", items, System.currentTimeMillis()-before);
    // => Time for plotting 16540 items is:  59910 ms
}
```

---

```
public void addToObservation(HashMap<Object, Vector<TimeSeriesDataItem>> plotData) {
    for (Object obj : plotData.keySet()) {
        SeriesHandler handler = m_series.get(obj);
        if (handler != null) {
            TimeSeries fullSeries = handler.getFullSeries();
            TimeSeries periodSeries = handler.getPeriodseries();
            for (TimeSeriesDataItem dataItem : plotData.get(obj)) {
                fullSeries.add(dataItem);
                periodSeries.add(dataItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Guy

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that would allow others to repeat your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Absent more details, any of several general optimizations should be considered:

- Invoke `setNotify(false)`, as suggested [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116135&p=175587&hilit=setNotify#p175587).
- Cache already calculated values, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13937078/230513).
- Adopt a paging strategy, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).
- Chart a summary of `average/time-unit` values; based on the `ChartEntity` seen in a `ChartMouseListener`, show an expanded subset in an adjacent panel.